# Grails does not resolve same-named Services as expected

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

I have two services with the same name in my Grails 2.4.4 project, called `RemittanceService`. One is in the package on `ph.bank` (which I created weeks ago) and another is on `ph.gov.advice.slip`(which I created today). Since now there are two instances of the service with the same name, I replaced all dependency-injection of `ph.bank.RemittanceService` from:

```
class ... {
    def remittanceService

    ...
}
```

into this:

```
class ... {
    def bankRemittanceService
    // added the word `bank` from its package

    ...
}
```

and the injections for `ph.gov.advice.slip.RemittanceService` into:

```
class ... {
    def slipRemittanceService
    // added the word `slip` from its package

    ...
}
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't point the respective `Service`, and instead, returns an error:

> **java.lang.NullPointerException**:
>   Cannot invoke method [...] on null object

I decided to revert it my previous code. When I return the declaration into:

```
def remittanceService
```

it always points to the `Service` found on `ph.bank`, never to my newly-created `Service`. My current fix is:

```
import ph.gov.advice.slip.RemittanceService

class ... {
    def slipRemittanceService = new RemittanceService()
    // Here I initialize it instead on how dependencies should be declared

    ...
}
```

Although, I felt that is wrong. Is there more Grails-ly way to do this?

Comment: Grails way is to rename your second service.. there is a reason for convention over configuration and default binding by name. Workaround is in the answer below from Taras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare beans in your `resources.groovy` file.

```
beans = {
  bankRemittanceService(ph.bank.RemittanceService) {
  }
  slipRemittanceService(ph.gov.advice.slip.RemittanceService) {
  }
}
```

now you can inject `bankRemittanceService` and `slipRemittanceService`